# Function context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

I want to achieve something similar to this:

A function `someFunction` has a method `.lockThis(<object>)` and when first called:

```
var foreverThis = {};

someFunction.lockThis(foreverThis);  

// ... or
// someFunction = someFunction.lockThis(foreverThis);
```

It will bind this function to the `<object>` so that the next (or any other) time this function is executed via as-function or as-method call, or via apply/call - it will have initially given `<object>` as this.

I can, of course, define `Function.prototype.lockThis` which will call the function via `.apply()/call()` and specify given object as a context, but then it will still be possible to substitute context of `someFunction` if someone calls it via `apply()` as well.

Is there a way to lock function context in JavaScript in a way that it will *always* have provided object as `this` without changing the code of the function itself?

Comment: So you're actually trying to make it so that if you do `someFunction.lockThis(something)`, every other time you call `someFunction` no matter where in the code it is, it'll pretend it's doing `something.someFunction`?

Comment: @SamuelReid, yes, something like this

Comment: Per your deleted question: `$(".class3")` selects all elements that have the `class3` class;
`$("div.class3")`selects all elements that have the `class3` class **and** are `div` elements. And that's all letting alone that modern browsers keep an index of classes to elements relation, and a mere class selector can be queried using `getElementsByClassName` while the other requires `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`+filtering by `tagName`. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
someFunction = someFunction.bind(foreverThis);
```

Comment: Yes, but if after `bind()` I run `someFunction.apply(evilContext)` it will have different `this`.

Comment: @mishik `bind` effectively creates a closure around the function and stores the supplied context to use when invoking the function later; so the apply calls that closure-wrapper (however the engine implements it), but doesn't affect how the closure calls the wrapped function using the previously stored context.

Comment: @SLaks, oh darn... how could I've been so blind...
I now feel kind of stupid writing such an essay to get one line correct answer :)